# Docker File in Google Cloud Run failing to install Dependencies - Failing on Pandas installation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a simple Python web app using Google's Cloud Run. However, I keep getting this error

```
Failed to build the app. Error: exit status 1. Docker build ran into internal error. Please retry. If this keeps happening, please open an issue..
```

I get this error specifically when it's installing Pandas. The Error log is below:
**Error Log:**

```
#9 [5/6] RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
#9 1.149 Collecting flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
#9 1.230   Downloading Flask-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
#9 1.270      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.9/96.9 kB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 1.350 Collecting requests (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
#9 1.357   Downloading requests-2.30.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
#9 1.369      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.5/62.5 kB 7.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 1.556 Collecting ptvsd (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
#9 1.566   Downloading ptvsd-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 MB)
#9 1.672      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.9/4.9 MB 48.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00

#9 2.022 Collecting numpy (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
#9 2.031   Downloading numpy-1.24.3.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
#9 2.198      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.9/10.9 MB 66.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 4.201   Installing build dependencies: started
#9 8.182   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#9 8.187   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#9 9.077   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#9 9.082   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
#9 9.775   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#9 9.896 Collecting langchain (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
#9 9.903   Downloading langchain-0.0.160-py3-none-any.whl (756 kB)
#9 9.928      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 756.3/756.3 kB 42.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 9.983 Collecting openai (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
#9 9.990   Downloading openai-0.27.6-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
#9 10.01      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 71.9/71.9 kB 8.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 10.07 Collecting gpt_index (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
#9 10.07   Downloading gpt_index-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (362 kB)
#9 10.09      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 362.2/362.2 kB 34.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 10.34 Collecting pandas==1.5.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
#9 10.35   Downloading pandas-1.5.2.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
#9 10.44      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.2/5.2 MB 62.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00

#9 11.88   Installing build dependencies: started
#9 34.99   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
#9 35.03   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 35.03   
#9 35.03   × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#9 35.03   │ exit code: 1
#9 35.03   ╰─> [262 lines of output]
#9 35.03       Collecting setuptools>=51.0.0
#9 35.03         Downloading setuptools-67.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
#9 35.03            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 18.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 35.03       Collecting wheel
#9 35.03         Downloading wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
#9 35.03            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 64.5/64.5 kB 8.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 35.03       Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.32
#9 35.03         Using cached Cython-0.29.34-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
#9 35.03       Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16
#9 35.03         Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
#9 35.03       Collecting numpy==1.19.3 (from oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16)
#9 35.03         Downloading numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
#9 35.03            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.3/7.3 MB 60.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 35.03         Installing build dependencies: started
#9 35.03         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#9 35.03         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#9 35.03         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#9 35.03         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
#9 35.03         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
#9 35.03         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03         × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#9 35.03         │ exit code: 1
#9 35.03         ╰─> [228 lines of output]
#9 35.03             Running from numpy source directory.
#9 35.03             setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
#9 35.03               run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
#9 35.03             Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
#9 35.03             Cythonizing sources
#9 35.03             blas_opt_info:
#9 35.03             blas_mkl_info:
#9 35.03             customize UnixCCompiler
#9 35.03               libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             blis_info:
#9 35.03               libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             openblas_info:
#9 35.03               libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
#9 35.03             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 35.03               libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_3_10_blas_info:
#9 35.03               libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_blas_threads_info:
#9 35.03             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 35.03               libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_blas_info:
#9 35.03               libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             accelerate_info:
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             /tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
#9 35.03                 Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
#9 35.03                 Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
#9 35.03                 A better performance should be easily gained by switching
#9 35.03                 Blas library.
#9 35.03               if self._calc_info(blas):
#9 35.03             blas_info:
#9 35.03               libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             /tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
#9 35.03                 Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
#9 35.03                 Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
#9 35.03                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
#9 35.03                 the BLAS environment variable.
#9 35.03               if self._calc_info(blas):
#9 35.03             blas_src_info:
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             /tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
#9 35.03                 Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
#9 35.03                 Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
#9 35.03                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
#9 35.03                 the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
#9 35.03               if self._calc_info(blas):
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
#9 35.03             lapack_opt_info:
#9 35.03             lapack_mkl_info:
#9 35.03               libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             openblas_lapack_info:
#9 35.03               libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             openblas_clapack_info:
#9 35.03               libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             flame_info:
#9 35.03               libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_3_10_threads_info:
#9 35.03             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03               libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_3_10_info:
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03               libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_threads_info:
#9 35.03             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03               libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             atlas_info:
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 35.03               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03               libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 35.03             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             lapack_info:
#9 35.03               libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             /tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
#9 35.03                 Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
#9 35.03                 Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
#9 35.03                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
#9 35.03                 the LAPACK environment variable.
#9 35.03               return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
#9 35.03             lapack_src_info:
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             /tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
#9 35.03                 Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
#9 35.03                 Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
#9 35.03                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
#9 35.03                 the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
#9 35.03               return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
#9 35.03               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
#9 35.03               FOUND:
#9 35.03                 language = c
#9 35.03                 define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03             /usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
#9 35.03               warnings.warn(msg)
#9 35.03             running dist_info
#9 35.03             running build_src
#9 35.03             build_src
#9 35.03             building py_modules sources
#9 35.03             creating build
#9 35.03             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9
#9 35.03             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy
#9 35.03             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/distutils
#9 35.03             building library "npymath" sources
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable gfortran
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable f95
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable ifort
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable ifc
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable lf95
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable pgfortran
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable nvfortran
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable f90
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable f77
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable fort
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable efort
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable efc
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable g77
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable g95
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable pathf95
#9 35.03             Could not locate executable nagfor
#9 35.03             don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
#9 35.03             Traceback (most recent call last):
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
#9 35.03                 main()
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
#9 35.03                 json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
#9 35.03                 return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-esajl9l_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
#9 35.03                 self.run_setup()
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-esajl9l_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
#9 35.03                 super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-esajl9l_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
#9 35.03                 exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
#9 35.03               File "setup.py", line 508, in <module>
#9 35.03                 setup_package()
#9 35.03               File "setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
#9 35.03                 setup(**metadata)
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
#9 35.03                 return old_setup(**new_attr)
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-esajl9l_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
#9 35.03                 return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
#9 35.03                 dist.run_commands()
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
#9 35.03                 self.run_command(cmd)
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#9 35.03                 cmd_obj.run()
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-esajl9l_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
#9 35.03                 egg_info.run()
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 24, in run
#9 35.03                 self.run_command("build_src")
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#9 35.03                 self.distribution.run_command(command)
#9 35.03               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#9 35.03                 cmd_obj.run()
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
#9 35.03                 self.build_sources()
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
#9 35.03                 self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
#9 35.03                 sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
#9 35.03               File "/tmp/pip-install-mara67th/numpy_c8c84956cf364a1ea55b46ca423355a3/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
#9 35.03                 source = func(extension, build_dir)
#9 35.03               File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 663, in get_mathlib_info
#9 35.03                 raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
#9 35.03             RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
#9 35.03             [end of output]
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#9 35.03       error: metadata-generation-failed
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03       × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#9 35.03       ╰─> See above for output.
#9 35.03       
#9 35.03       note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#9 35.03       hint: See above for details.
#9 35.03       [end of output]
```

These are the details of my Docker file and my Requirements.txt:

**Docker File:**

```
# Python image to use.
FROM python:3.9-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy the requirements file used for dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .

#upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the working directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Run app.py when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

**Requirements.txt:**

```
flask
requests
ptvsd # Required for debugging.
numpy
langchain
openai
gpt_index
pandas==1.5.2
tiktoken
#pickle
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried going through the older threads, but didn't find sufficient guidance. Apologies if this is somehow still a duplicate.

What have I tried?

- In Docker file, I first started with Python version 3.10. Then I downgraded to 3.9, since I presumed (wrongly) that maybe the new versions of Numpy or Pandas just aren't compatible yet.
- I tried upgrading pip in the docker file (as can be seen) - that seem to have been a common issue in similar cases in the past.
- I tried Installing the latest version of Numpy first (which loads very well) and I have tried installing an older version of Numpy as well (1.24.0) - both independently install well.
- I tried Installing the latest version of Pandas first and an older version of Pandas (1.5.3) - Both of them fail when they try to Install Numpy.

Comment: You have error messages. Have you researched what those errors mean? The first item I note is that the install is looking for the C compiler which is not part of your build. Start with this numpy error: `setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates`.

Comment: The comment of @JohnHanley was my first guess. Try with another base image, the "non" alpine one maybe.

Comment: Should be the solution, I read an article mentioning that `libc` was missing in the alpine version. https://medium.com/swlh/alpine-slim-stretch-buster-jessie-bullseye-bookworm-what-are-the-differences-in-docker-62171ed4531d

Comment: @JohnHanley I I will try that! But before that I tried guillaume 's solution and that worked right away! Thanks - That seems to have been the problem.

Comment: That is what I was suggesting with `is looking for the C compiler which is not part of your build`. The key to understanding is that many Python packages are written in C. Without the proper base image, you must install the build tools. Otherwise, package installation fails. Review this link on multi-stage builds. You start with a full image of tools and then use a reduced size (slim) image for deployment: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-multi-stage-builds